# Top-left element of inverse of real symmetric matrix

Tags: inverse, symmetric-matrices

Let
$$
M =\begin{pmatrix} a & v^\top \\ v & B \end{pmatrix},
$$
with $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \neq 0$, $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1 \times n-1}$ invertible and symmetric.

What is a simple expression for $(M^{-1})_{11}$, i.e., a *nice* simplification of the block inversion formula?

My suspect (coming from another calculation) would be that
$$
(M^{-1})_{11} = \left(a - v^\top B^{-1} v\right)^{-1},
$$
but I cannot prove it.

**EDIT:**

In light of the accepted answer below, we have
$$
(M^{-1})_{11} = \frac{\det(B)}{\det(M)},
$$
but, since $B$ is invertible, it holds (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_determinant))
$$
\det(M)= \det(B)\det(a- v^\top B^{-1}v)=\det(B)(a- v^\top B^{-1}v).
$$
Hence
$$
(M^{-1})_{11} = \frac{\det(B)}{\det(B)(a- v^\top B^{-1}v)} = (a- v^\top B^{-1}v)^{-1},
$$
my suspect.

Comment: Oh, I just saw your update, that's nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're can find a solution in the following formula for the inverse of the matrix $M$: $$M^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det M} C^T,$$ where $C$ is the cofactor matrix, i.e. the matrix with entries $C_{ij}=\det D^{ij}$ where $D^{ij}$ is *the matrix* obtained from $M$ by removing its $i$th row and $j$th column.

In your case, $D^{11}=B$, hence $$(M^{-1})_{11}=\frac{\det B}{\det M}.$$

Here's the wikipedia article on this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)#Inverse_of_a_matrix